# How to get a SOAP 1.2 to call the service vs. return the landing page

Tags: .net, web-services, soap, asmx

My primary question is how to enable/set a service to allow/use SOAP 1.2 instead of redirecting to the service landing page, where a WSDL reference and the service methods are listed as links.

A colleague within my company has a web service (ASMX) that works fine under SOAP 1.1 and 1.2 in dev environments.  When the same is promoted to UAT (IIS-Server 2016?), it only works under SOAP 1.1.

**Update**  Using Postman, I've found the service landing page is what the server is attempting to return to clients calling it instead of passing the request to the service.

**Edit** Now knowing what the server is attempting to respond, some details previously included are varied symptoms of the same underlying issue.

Calling using SOAP 1.2 from SoapUI and the intended client service, both receive messages to the effect of (SoapUI version):

> The server cannot service the request because the media type is unsupported.

This makes sense because a web service expects XML but is instead receiving an HTML page.

However, testing against SOAP 1.1 gives different results.  Calling from SoapUI, I receive successful response from the service.  Calling from my .NET service using the basicHttpBinding, it still returns the landing page (HTML) vs. calling the service.

It is acting as though details about what is placing the request (header info maybe?) are getting interpreted by IIS that it should return browser-friendly HTML instead of passing the request to the service.

One other oddity I notice with SoapUI is that I can add a WSDL for the dev service without appending the ?wsdl to the end of the URL.  In UAT, it only works when I explicitly append ?wsdl.  Not doing so gives:

> Error loading [http://uat.service.com/services/sendmessage.asmx]: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: does not close tag
>   .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case others stumble upon this, our issue was twofold:

First, there was something in the UAT web.config that was blocking SOAP1.2.  Unfortunately, I only know my colleague copied his dev config over UAT and that part started working.

Second, the server was redirecting to HTTPS.  It turns out Dev was not configured this way and indeed calls were going through under HTTP.  This one was found by inspecting Fiddler, which showed a 302 redirect where dev had shown a "happy path" 200.  Updating the client binding to use HTTPS and the endpoint url to do the same fixed the rest.

```
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="SendMessageSoap12">
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12"/>
      <httpsTransport/>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>

      <endpoint address="https://serverservice.com/services/sendmessage.asmx" 
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="SendMessageSoap12" 
            contract="StatService.SendWorkflowMessageSoap" name="SendMessageSoap12"/>
```